# Does the Core Foundation objects are automatically released by ARC or do we need manual memory management?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation, xcode-instruments

In my code am creating a **Core Foundation** object, and from the apple documentation i came to know that

> "The life span of a Core Foundation object is determined by its
>   reference count" https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Articles/lifecycle.html

So I highly doubt that whether the core foundation objects are released by ARC or do we need to release by writing **CFRelease(myobject)**

Am using Xcode 6.4,and presently in my code am not using any **CFRelease(myobject)** for releasing my Core Foundation objects,and still I couldn't find any **memory leak in xcode instruments(Leak)**..

So my question is whether ARC will take care of releasing Core Foundation objects..??

as I just came across a statement like,

> Recall that ARC only deals with Objective-C objects. It doesn’t manage
>   the retain and release of CoreFoundation objects which are not
>   Objective-C objects.http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

So if any one came across the same problem and found a solution pls do share...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must call `CFRelease` to release Core Foundation object.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW1

> The compiler does not automatically manage the lifetimes of Core Foundation objects; you must call `CFRetain` and `CFRelease`.

Or you can use `__bridge_transfer` or `CFBridgingRelease` to move the ownership of the Core Foundation object to the under the Objective-C ARC object ownership.

> - `__bridge_transfer` or `CFBridgingRelease` moves a non-Objective-C pointer to Objective-C and also transfers ownership to ARC.
>
>   - ARC is responsible for relinquishing ownership of the object.

So the following case, the `NSString* __strong name` variable has the ownership of the Core Foundation object. The Core Foundation object is automatically released when `name = nil;` or the end of the scope of `name` variable.

```
NSString *name = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
```

Or

```
NSString *name = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...can you list out what are all the other frameworks like core foundation framework ,that ARC will not take care..??

Comment: AFAIK, Address Book Framework. But it is deprecated from iOS 9. Anyway, why don't you accept this answer? :)

Comment: @KazukiSakamoto Could you please complete your correct and helpful answer with links to the Apple documentation on using __bridge_transfer and CFBridgingRelease() in the context of ARC ?